# Google deployment manager runtime policy metadata

Tags: google-deployment-manager

What is the difference between Google deployment manager `UPDATE_ON_CHANGE` and `UPDATE_ALWAYS` metadata runtime policy ? An example highlighting the difference would be very useful.

I searched through the documentation but could not find any useful references. There are a few hints on the github repository but they seem to be succinct and not verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UPDATE_ALWAYS` - call the API for create or update changes in the deployment

`CREATE` - only call on create

`UPDATE_ON_CHANGE` - call when the action changes

`DELETE` - call on deletes

This is the closest to a definition I could find.

**Reference** - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/cloudbuild